# Product form in admin: adding a field in the basic area

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, adminform, magento-2.1.3

I have added a custom attribute to the product entity. It is visible in the back-office, and the value is properly saved, it works fine.

However, using the .xml file, I would like to override the display (for exemple, for a select yes/no, I would like to use the built-in switch icon of Magento).
To do that, I have to add a xml file to my module, and write inside the data related to my field, in a specific fieldset.

The problem is here, I don't know the name of the basic (default) fieldset in the product form. I managed to do it in the category form, but not in the product one. Any Idea?